# Azure v2.0 Refresh Token, returns another Refresh Token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, refresh-token

Azure AD is granting my application access tokens and a refresh token.  When I use the refresh token to get a new access token, in return I get a new access token and a NEW refresh token.

Azure AD does not specify like Google Suite how many refresh tokens are allowed.  But to the root of the problem, I don't want a refresh token being recreated and sent back, every time I use a refresh token.  What is happening here? How do I stop this?

Comment: … why don't you want a new refresh token?

Comment: Why do I want a new refresh token? I don't want multiple refresh tokens floating around that take 90 days of inactivity to become blacklisted.

Answer (score 2):

Returning of new refresh token is part of the [OpenID Connect Protocol Specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RefreshTokenResponse) which references the [OAuth Authorization Framework section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.1) for clarity.

Indeed the return of a refresh token is optional, but the implementation in Azure AD is so that it always returns a refresh token. I personally see no issue with it. Just throw away the last saved refresh token and keep the new one you got.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot control this, it is done by design. It is also in complience with the [OAuth 2.0 spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5):

> The authorization server authenticates the client and validates the refresh token, and if valid, issues a new access token  (and,optionally, a new refresh token).

As for "floating out there", this only happens if you *make* it happen. If your app "forgets" the old refresh token then it is gone.